# unable to open home page when using SAML Single Sign On

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0

I have created two way to login into my site. first way i have implemented spring security. In that spring security is for `/user/home` path i.e if path contain `/user` then it should be done by spring security. this is working fine. Now problem is
I have implemented SAML signle sign on and when i get successful authentication, i want to goto home page. but when i am doing this again it is asking the login credentails in spring security. how can i directly goto home page without  spring security in this case.

spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <!-- <http-basic/> -->
        <form-login login-page="/login/loginUser" authentication-failure-url="/user/failed_login" />
        <logout logout-url="/user/logout"/>
</http>
```

can i dynamically disable spring security at run time.